# Selecting Previous Sibling with a Certain Class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to figure this out for hours and I'm just not understanding what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to get the parent checkbox of a certain class when the child checkbox is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-header" id="heading6">
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input program_checkbox" id="program6" value="6" checked="">
              <a class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse6" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse6">Maine Ecological Reserves Program</a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse6" style="margin-left:24px;" class="accordion-collapse collapse show ml-4" aria-labelledby="heading6" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
         <div class="form-group form-check pl-4">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input file_checkbox program6" id="package243" value="program_data/6/packages/1646756076.zip" checked="">
             <label class="form-check-label" for="package243">1646756076.zip</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group form-check pl-4">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input file_checkbox program6" id="scriptundefined" value="program_data/6/scripts/MEER_munger.py" checked="">
             <label class="form-check-label" for="scriptundefined">MEER_munger.py</label>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-header" id="heading9">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input program_checkbox" id="program9" value="9">
             <a class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse9" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse9">Vermont State Lands Continuous Forest Inventory</a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse9" style="margin-left:24px;" class="accordion-collapse collapse show ml-4" aria-labelledby="heading9" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">No files for this project
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.file_checkbox', function(){
         if($(".file_checkbox:checked").length < $(".file_checkbox").length) { 
            console.log($(this).parent().parent().prevAll('.program_checkbox'));
        }
   });
```

I've tried so many combinations of parent/prev/next/sibling I'm losing my mind, and for some reason I can't get to the previous .program_checkbox to uncheck it...

What am I missing?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- With checkbox use `change` instead of `click`
- `parent()` select one level up
- `prev()` previous element on same level
- `prevAll()` also on the same level

With `$(this).parent().parent()` you reached to `class="accordion-collapse collapse` element then you need to use `prev()` to reach to previous `accordion-item` then use `find('.program-checkbox')` to select the desired element

Also instead of repeat `parent().parent()...` you can only use `.closest()`

- See the next example

```js
$(document).on('change', '.program_checkbox', function(){
    $(this).closest('.accordion-item').next().find('.file_checkbox').prop("checked" , this.checked);
});

$(document).on('change', '.file_checkbox', function(){
   let file_checked = $(this).closest(".accordion-collapse").find(".file_checkbox:checked").length,
       program_checkbox = $(this).closest(".accordion-collapse").prev().find('.program_checkbox');
   if(file_checked) { 
    program_checkbox.prop("checked" , true);
  }else{
    program_checkbox.prop("checked" , false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-header" id="heading6">
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input program_checkbox" id="program6" value="6" checked="">
              <a class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse6" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse6">Maine Ecological Reserves Program</a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse6" style="margin-left:24px;" class="accordion-collapse collapse show ml-4" aria-labelledby="heading6" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
         <div class="form-group form-check pl-4">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input file_checkbox program6" id="package243" value="program_data/6/packages/1646756076.zip" checked="">
             <label class="form-check-label" for="package243">1646756076.zip</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group form-check pl-4">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input file_checkbox program6" id="scriptundefined" value="program_data/6/scripts/MEER_munger.py" checked="">
             <label class="form-check-label" for="scriptundefined">MEER_munger.py</label>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-header" id="heading9">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input program_checkbox" id="program9" value="9">
             <a class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse9" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse9">Vermont State Lands Continuous Forest Inventory</a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse9" style="margin-left:24px;" class="accordion-collapse collapse show ml-4" aria-labelledby="heading9" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">No files for this project
    </div>
</div>
```